# Python - How to append to a list if the element is not already part of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists, one with elements and other one being empty. I want to copy elements from the first list to the second only if the element is not already part of the second list.

The below code works:

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]
listB = []

for i in listA:
    for key in i.keys():
        if key not in listB:
            listB.append(key)

print(listB)
```

It prints the below output which is correct:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Z']
```

**Question 1:**

I want to replace those four lines of the *for* loop with a single line. So I wrote the below single line and it's printing the object itself instead of the elements in the list.

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]
listB = []

listB.append(key for i in listA for key in i.keys() if key not in listB)

print(listB)
```

It's printing the generator object as below instead of the elements:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000020AC0334120>]
```

How can I get the correct output by replacing for loops with a single line?

**Question 2**

To solve question 1, I took a temporary list to generate the elements, but it's appending the duplicate elements as well. The if condition is not working.

Here's the code:

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]
listB = []

temp_list = [key for i in listA for key in i.keys() if key not in listB]
listB.extend(temp_list)

print(listB)
```

And the output is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'Z', 'D']
```

This output shows the `listB` contains duplicates for 'A' and 'D'.
Why is the *if* condition in the list comprehension not working?

Comment: "I want to replace those 4 lines of the for loop with single line. ": (Counter) argument: why? It works, it's clear and clean Python code.

Comment: Is order important? If not, use a set comprehension, e.g. `{k for d in listA for k in d}`

Comment: @9769953 I just want to reduce the no of lines. Also I heard that generators/comprehensions are efficient than for loops.

Comment: While reducing number of lines can be good, it might also impede clarity of the code, so that's something to weight properly (which can be a hard thing to do). And efficiency has to be 1/ measured (speed? memory usage?), and 2/ deemed useful. Running slow code once is can still be more efficient that running fast code many times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict.fromkeys()`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys

it will preserve the order as well

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]

listB = list(dict.fromkeys(k for d in listA for k in d))

print(listB)
#['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is you can only append 1 element. The right method is to use extend.

But then, you second question did use extend. However, the `temp_list` was created when `listB` is still empty. That is why you get the duplicates because the expression `if key not in listB` is always false.

The correct answer is the combination of 1 and 2:

```py
listB = []
listB.extend(key for i in listA for key in i if key not in listB)
```

A couple of notes

- The expression `for key in i.keys()` can be shorten to `for key in i`
- This works because

  1. You are using `extend`, which adds many elements instead of `append`, which adds only 1 element
  2. You don't create a temp list for the reason discussed above

Going further, if you don't care about order of the keys then use `set`, which eliminate duplicates for free:

```py
setB = set(key for i in listA for key in i)
```

If you still want to have the result as a list, an alternative is to use `itertools.chain` for a cleaner code:

```py
import itertools

listB = []
listB.extend(key for key in itertools.chain(*listA) if key not in listB)
```

Finally, you can combine the `set` solution with the `itertools.chain` solution, which is the shortest:

```py
import itertools

setB = set(itertools.chain(*listA))
```

Comment: You can `chain.from_iterable` to avoid star-unpacking here. I'm not sure if it has any benefit now, but it exists for this specific case for some reason.

Comment: *"the shortest"* - `setB = set().union(*listA)`

Comment: @STerliakov That's needed if you want lazy or if your source is even infinite.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, you can use a set to keep track of elements that have already been added to listB.

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
         {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
         {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]
listB = set()

listB.update(key for i in listA for key in i.keys() if key not in listB)

print(list(listB))
```

For Question 2, the reason you are getting duplicate elements is that the `if key not in listB` condition is checked against listB, which is empty at the beginning. So, initially, all elements from listA are added to temp_list. To fix this, you can modify with an if condition to filter out duplicates like this:

```
temp_list = [key for i in listA for key in i.keys() if key not in listB]
listB.extend(key for key in temp_list if key not in listB)
```

Comment: I have verified with my code and both will give the correct result: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Z']. The key will be updated if it hasn't been presented in listB.

Comment: You are right, it does work... Using the generator, `listB` is indeed updated between all the checks, so the `in` does work, but I wonder if that's really documented behavior; in any case it's not really intuitive IMHO. Also, in the first version (using `set`), `in` is not necessary at all, and in the second (using `list`) it's O(n²)...

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct output by replacing for loops with a single line, you can use set:

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]

listB = [*{key for i in listA for key in i}]

print(listB)

# ['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'Z', 'D']
```

to preserve order use dict comprehension:

```
listA = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2},
           {'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5},
           {'A': 26, 'Z': 1, 'D': 23}]

listB = [*{key:_ for i in listA for key,_ in i.items()}]

print(listB)

# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Z']
```