List Comprehension to find unique numbers in list
L1 = [1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
l2 = []

print([lambda x: l2.append(x) for x in L1 if x not in l2])

I am expecting the code should return the unique numbers in the list using list comprehension in python.

Printing result of a list comprehension isn't what your expecting. You don't need lambda.

you can find à solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324133/python-how-to-append-to-a-list-if-the-element-is-not-already-part-of-it

It’s not clear from your question if it it’s important to maintain the order of the list. This is import because the efficient way of doing this using a set does not preserve order.

@Mark: Note: The approach using dict.fromkeys, while slightly less efficient, is still big-O identical to using a set, and does preserve order from CPython 3.6 onwards (and any Python implementation from 3.7 onwards). Both set and dict.fromkeys approaches are O(n) solutions with the work handed off to the C layer, the dict.fromkeys approach just has a slightly higher constant multiplier. I'm guessing the OP isn't super-performance sensitive here, and it's probably best to preserved order anyway (I'd favor set only if it was going to be followed by sorted anyway).

why do you want to use a list comprehension to find the unique values in a list?

You've got several problems:

You're creating a list of lambda functions, not calling any of them
If you fix this by changing to print([l2.append(x) for x in L1 if x not in l2]), it still won't work as you expect, because you'll be making and printing a list of Nones (the return value of list.append). l2 will be modified as you expect, you just won't see it.
If you split the work to:
[l2.append(x) for x in L1 if x not in l2]
print(l2)

it will work, but it's incredibly unPythonic. List comprehensions are a functional construct; they should receive an input iterable, produce an output list, and otherwise be entirely self-contained. Using them for side-effects, and especially using them primarily/only for side-effects, is counter-intuitive in the extreme.

If you want your current design, use a normal for loop, not a listcomp:
L1 = [1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
l2 = []
for x in L1:
    if x not in l2:
        l2.append(x)
print(l2)

But modern Python can actually do exactly what you're doing far more efficiently, because as of 3.6 (3.7 as a language guarantee) dicts are insertion-ordered, so rather than the O(n²) cost paid above, you can just do:
L1 = [1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
l2 = list(dict.fromkeys(L1))
print(l2)

creating a temporary dict (in O(n) time) to uniquify while preserving order, then creating a list from the dicts keys (another O(n) step, but even cheaper than the dict creation).

The list(dict.fromkeys(L1)) does have one weakness; the values being uniquified must be hashable. But the OP's case is for int inputs, so this isn't a limitation here. For non-hashable, but sortable inputs, a O(n log n) solution is still possible, improving on the O(n²) of the loop-and-check approach, but it's also far more complicated, so it's arguably okay to use the simpler the O(n²) approach if input sizes won't be large enough to cause problems. For hashable stuff though, list(dict.fromkeys(L1)) is simpler, faster, and far more concise, there's literally no downside.

idealy you can use set or dict.fromkeys like this:
l2 = list(dict.fromkeys(L1))

# OR
l2 = list(set(L1))

Full Example

it should be noted that [l2.append(x) for x in L1 if x not in l2] is incredibly inefficient. This code really shouldn't see the light of day. Just convert it to a set and then back to a list

Not only that, but it's using side-effects of a list comp to build a completely separate list. This code should not be used.

You are right @roganjosh

Note: Using set will lose existing order (which the OP's code, if fixed, would not do). dict.fromkeys will preserve it in the same way (so long as you're using 3.6 or above, and I really hope you are).

The issue is that you're creating a list of lambdas rather than executing them. Try this instead:
L1 = [1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
l2 = []
[l2.append(x) for x in L1 if x not in l2]
print(l2)
This will give you the unique numbers in L1.
